# Triggering an Immediately resize with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I made a little code with jQuery ( not the best jquery user yet. )

```
    $(function(){
var theDiv = $('.blury-format-image .post-info .title');
var theThumbnail = $('.blury-format-image .thumbnail').innerHeight();
var theThumbnailW = $('.blury-format-image .thumbnail').innerWidth();   
theDiv.innerHeight( theThumbnail );
theDiv.innerWidth( theThumbnailW );
});
```

which just resizes the div as the height and width of the thumbnail, anyway it only works when I refresh the page which is a problem! because if a mobile user tried the landscape mode the dimensions will look really bad!

is there's somehow to trigger it immediately with any resize action? ty.

Comment: Are you talking about window resize? There's the `$(window).on('resize'` event

Comment: $(function(){ is document.ready()  it will only be hit on page refresh event

Comment: you could refactor the code into a function and then call the function in an event,,,

Comment: so i used the $window.on('resize') and it worked perfectly fine in every time I resize the screen but not when I normally open the website lol, how do I fix that?

Comment: dont go for shorthand notations.... use **$(document).ready(function() {});**
 instead of  ** $(function(){});** kinda makes the picture more clear

Comment: @AhmedSafiEl-Dien  mark the answer please :) if your issue got solved

Comment: oh i did now, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this as separeate Function called ResizeDiv

```js
function ResizeDiv(){
        var theDiv = $('.blury-format-image .post-info .title');
        var theThumbnail = $('.blury-format-image .thumbnail').innerHeight();
        var theThumbnailW = $('.blury-format-image .thumbnail').innerWidth();   
        theDiv.innerHeight( theThumbnail );
        theDiv.innerWidth( theThumbnailW );
   };
```

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   ResizeDiv(); //would be called on page Refresh
})
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
       ResizeDiv();  // this would be called on resize event
    })
</script>
```

because

> $(function(){

is like $(document).ready()

Any code directly inside will be called on document gets ready..which only happens on page refresh... hence you now know why it works only on page refresh

Comment: it worked perfectly fine every time I resize the browser, but what about when I normally open the browser?

Comment: good question...then you call the ResizeDiv() twice...once inside the resize event..and once in doucment.ready

Comment: let me modify my answer

Comment: hahaa,,,shokran al habib ...accept this as answer ...and let me know if any further issues

Answer (score 0):

ref : https://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(function()
   rez();
   $(window).resize(function() {
     rez();
   });
});

function rez(){    
   var theDiv = $('.blury-format-image .post-info .title');
   var theThumbnail = $('.blury-format-image .thumbnail').innerHeight();
   var theThumbnailW = $('.blury-format-image .thumbnail').innerWidth();   
   theDiv.innerHeight( theThumbnail );
   theDiv.innerWidth( theThumbnailW );
}
```